# Undefined offset 1 errors on using "Business Connect" theme with drupal 7

Tags: php, themes, drupal-7

I installed the "Business Connect" theme in drupal 7.10, this theme is working fine, but some time I receive these error messages. If I install another theme then no error messages display, it means that the problem is with "Business Connect" theme’s template.php file.

Error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in businessconnect_process_page() (line 44 of 
C:\xampp\htdocs\my-site-name\sites\all\themes\businessconnect\template.php).

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in businessconnect_process_page() (line 44 of 
C:\xampp\htdocs\my-site-name\sites\all\themes\businessconnect\template.php).

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in businessconnect_process_page() (line 44 of 
\C:\xampp\htdocs\my-site-name\sites\all\themes\businessconnect\template.php).
```

Template.php code :

```
if ($variables['is_front'])
{
    $variable=$variables['title'];
    $text=(explode(" ", $variable));
    $variables['title'] = '<span>'.$text[0].' '.$text[1].' '.'<span class="title_default">'.$text[2].' '.$text[3].'</span>'.'</span>';
}
```

line# 44:

```
    $variables['title'] = '<span>'.$text[0].' '.$text[1].' '.'<span class="title_default">'.$text[2].' '.$text[3].'</span>'.'</span>';
```

Comment: It looks like whomever created the "Business Connect" them needs to learn to program with `E_ALL | E_STRICT` enabled :)

Comment: Please get in to contact with your themes vendor and discuss the issue there. Otherwise wait until a user of the same theme shows up here which might not be the best place to expect that.

Comment: Also [please read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) which type of questions are acceptable on this site. It's a programming site, not a specific I have a problem with a Theme of XYZ type of site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of @hakre getting mad at me ... :)

The error message is the result of the business connect script referencing variables that don't actually exist ($text[1], $text[2], $text[3]). You can correct the problem by replacing line #44 with the following:

```
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
  $var = "mytext$i";
  $$var = isset($text[$i]) ? $text[$i] : '';
}
$variables['title'] = '<span>'.$mytext0.' '.$mytext1.' <span class="title_default">'.$mytext2.' '.$mytext3.'</span></span>';
```

Hacking up the internals of third-party scripts isn't usually a good idea ... but in a case like this it's unlikely the insufficiently experienced person who created the theme will be correcting the issue any time soon.

Comment: Thanks you so much Mr. rdlowrey, you solved my problem. Again thanks I appreciated for you code and help.